# Error when running cassandra on Google Cloud on external ip - Failed to bind port 9042 on 34.89.109.98

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to make `Cassandra` run on Google Cloud using external ip of the VM. But I am getting error `Failed to bind port 9042 on 34.89.109.98`. As far as I can see, I have followed the rules of setting firewall rules but I am still not able to resolve the issue. I have attached the pics of my configuration for your reference.

1) The firewall rule is

[image]

2) The list of all the rules is

[image]

3) The VM is

[image]

More Information
I followed the steps in https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-on-debian-9/ to install Cassandra. This automatically started cassandra. Then I killed cassandra, changed the ip address to external IP in `cassandra.yaml` file and started it again. It didn't work. Then I started working around with VPN settings.

Part of the message dump after I issue the command to start cassandra `/usr/sbin/cassandra -f`

```
INFO  [main] 2019-12-18 16:09:40,755 StorageService.java:1521 - JOINING: Finish joining ring
INFO  [main] 2019-12-18 16:09:40,826 StorageService.java:2442 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  [main] 2019-12-18 16:09:41,027 NativeTransportService.java:68 - Netty using native Epoll event loop
INFO  [main] 2019-12-18 16:09:41,071 Server.java:158 - Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final
.452812a, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.44.Final.452812
a, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.44.Final.452812a
, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-tcnative=
netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork26.142ecbb, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-native-
epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.44.Final.452
812a, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.4
4.Final.452812a]
INFO  [main] 2019-12-18 16:09:41,071 Server.java:159 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /35.197.238.136:9042 (
unencrypted)...
Exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException) encountered during startup: Failed to bind port 9042 on 35.197.238.136.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on 35.197.238.136.
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:163)
        at java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4769)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.NativeTransportService.start(NativeTransportService.java:124)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.startNativeTransport(CassandraDaemon.java:696)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:546)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:635)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:742)
ERROR [main] 2019-12-18 16:09:41,100 CassandraDaemon.java:759 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on 35.197.238.136.
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:163) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4769) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.NativeTransportService.start(NativeTransportService.java:124) ~[apache-cass
andra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.startNativeTransport(CassandraDaemon.java:696) [apache-cass
andra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:546) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.ja
r:3.11.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:635) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5
.jar:3.11.5]
```

Comment: I hear that the error message is "Failed to bind port 9042 on 34.89.109.98".  Can you elaborate on this?  Where is the message being issued?  Are there any stackdriver log records being issued?  Was there a recipe you followed to install Cassandra?

Comment: I have a gut feel ... and this is wild speculation ... that you may have configured YOUR software installation for the software to use the 34.x.x.x IP address because your logic said "That's my public IP and I only want my database to respond to that IP".  If yes, then that is likely the error.  Your Compute Engine doesn't have an interface with that public IP ... only its VPC interface.

Comment: updated the question. The IP is public IP/interface for my compute machine. I didn't specify it when installing cassandra. The IP in cassandra.yaml is `35.197.238.136` which is now the new ip of my compute machine. I got the new IP because I restarted the machine. The new error is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on 35.197.238.136` which I think shows that the `34...` ip isn't hardcoded anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the Cassandra cassandra.yaml file you can bind your Cassandra server to an IP address on which it is listening.  The default is 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and is not suitable for external connections.

The address values you can use are the addresses that the Compute Engine has associated with it.  These can be discovered using:

```
ip addr
```

It is important to realize that a Compute Engine may *appear* to have a public IP address when shown in the GCP Console, but that is not a network interface *on* the Compute Engine.  In the example in your original question, the Compute Engine IP address would be `10.154.0.4`.  This is the address you want to set in your configuration file.

See also this document which describes setting up Cassandra on GCP:

- [Spinning up a Cassandra Cluster on Google Cloud (for free) with just a browser](https://medium.com/@sreekar.anugu/spinning-up-a-cassandra-cluster-on-google-cloud-for-free-with-just-a-browser-8dd5f64b426d)

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful indeed. Things work if I use `10.xxx` address. I want to connect to the `cassandra` compute machine from my laptop (say cqlsh running on my laptop). I can't do that if I use `10.xxx` address as it is not even ping-able from my laptop.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful but to be honest, I am confused between the two IP address and can't figure out how to connect to cassandra from outside. It should be easy as I want to eventually connect with cassandra from my web server which might hosted somewhere else.

Comment: I think I get it but please let me know if I haven't. I have to use the `10.xxx` address to bind cassadra to the ip of the NIC as that is the actual address. But to connect from outside, I'll have to use the `35.xxx` address. It seems to be way to avoid exposing the `10.xxx` address to outside world. However, I'll have to enable firewall before the outside work can connect using `35.xxx` address.

Comment: The way to think about it is that your Compute Engine (your VM) has network interfaces.  These are connected to the VPC network.  These addresses are private to the VPC only.  It is these network interfaces that an app (eg. Cassandra) can bind to.  The public IP address is created DISTINCT from your VM and is the associated with a route/path such that when an Internet request arrives at the public IP address, it is then routed over VPC to terminate at your private IP address.