# why am I not able to telnet to a Google cloud machine even when all access is allowed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

To experiment with VPN, I have created a VPN firewall rule that allows access to all the ports from all the IPs.

[image]

But when I telnet to the machine from my windows machine, I get error `telnet 35.197.238.136
Connecting To 35.197.238.136...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed`

Why am I not able to telnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely story is that that, by default, a default Compute Engine doesn't have the telnet server software installed.  If it is not installed, it is obviously not listening.  If it is not listening, then a client connection to port 23 (the default telnet port) will fail.

You can install the Telnet server on your Compute Engine using:

```
sudo apt-get install telnetd
```

You will also have to "think ahead".  Once telnet is running and you connect a client, you will be asked to login.  Logging in requires a userid/password pair.  By default, your Compute Engine has none.  Consider creating a user using the Linux command `adduser`.

You might also want to consider your usage of telnet as compared to SSH.  It appears that SSH has all but supplanted telnet connections these days.

Comment: Thanks Kolban. My actual issue is in the following question. I thought that testing via telnet could be a good way to check if I am setting VPN correctly. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393296/error-when-running-cassandra-on-google-cloud-on-external-ip-failed-to-bind-por

Comment: `telenetd` should be `telnetd`